# PHP Проверка на пустоту полей при добавлении

Tags: php, база-данных

Есть php документ, который выполняет добавление строки из 3 столбцов `fname(имя) sname(отчество) score(счёт)` в базу. Есть случаи, когда добавляются записи со значением 0 в поле score. Как сделать проверку и не добавлять подобные записи.

```
    <?php
$dbhost = "localhost";         
$dbuser = "Логин";       
$dbpassword = 'Пароль';   
$dbname = "vladiksan1998";         

$sname = $_POST['sname'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$score = $_POST['score'];

$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
if (false === $link)
   die ('Error database connect');
$select_result = mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
if (false === $select_result)
   die ('Error database select<');
$query = "INSERT INTO records VALUES('$fname','$sname','$score')";
$query_result = mysql_query($query, $link);
if (false === $query_result)
   die ('Error database SQL query');
$close_result = mysql_close($link);
if (false === $close_result)
   die ('Error database close');
   ?>
```

Либо можно как то изменить вывод, что бы нулевые поля не выводились

Вывод:

```
    <?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'login', 'pass')
    or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('vladiksan1998') or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');

$query = 'SELECT fname, sname, score FROM records';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error());

echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if($line['score'] != 0){
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td>" . $line['fname'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td>" . $line['sname'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td>" . $line['score'] . "</td>\n";
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
}
echo "</table>\n";
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Но не хотелось бы хранить в таблице нули.

Comment: Вопрос решен. Но изменением вывода. Нужный вариант в вопрос напишу.  Но всё же интересует вопрос можно ли их просто не добавлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем что бы не добавлялись, то вместо вот этого

```
$query = "INSERT INTO records VALUES('$fname','$sname','$score')";
$query_result = mysql_query($query, $link);
```

Добавь

```
if($score != 0)
{
  $query = "INSERT INTO records VALUES('$fname','$sname','$score')";
  $query_result = mysql_query($query, $link);
}
```

---

Что бы не выводились сделай SQL запрос

```
$query = 'SELECT fname , sname , score FROM records WHERE score != 0';
```

P.S Невероятный код у начинающих. Вам удобно это читать самим? ))

Comment: Честно говоря да. Удобно) Как бы странно это не звучало.